# x86 assembly int 16h flush keyboard buffer

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

I am writing program that works on boot sector and try use BIOS interrupt 16h
to read keyboard input, but I don't know how to flush keyboard buffer to read 
next key input.

```
    mov ax,0604h
    int 16h
    mov ah,11h
    int 16h
    cmp ah,1fh;for S
    jne nxt1
    mov [dest],00000000b
    nxt1:
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) for list of BIOS interrupt.

Comment: You flush a buffer by reading its content, and not using it, until the buffer is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

Although I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, I have an idea.

The interrupt `int 16h 00h` not only reads from the keyboard buffer, but it also removes the key read from the buffer and stores the ASCII format in `AL`. That way, the buffer won't continue to fill and fill.

More information [here](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0229.HTM)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to clean any buffers with BIOS keyboard input.

The following program takes any number of inputs, and prints them to the screen like a text editor:

```
start:

    /* Read to al. */
    mov $0x00, %ah
    int $0x16

    /* Print al. */
    mov $0x0E, %ah
    int $0x10

    jmp start
```

Working example with full build boilerplate [on my GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/cba0757990843f412b14dffad45467ad0034d286/bios_keyboard_loop.S).

Comment: I've liked your answers in general however I have noticed that you do direct people to your on github as a form of self promotion. You do inline the code snippets that are relevant which is good, but you really should disclose that the github links in your answers are your site. This [Meta SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/271768) discusses the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Since there is a pattern to your answers promoting your repo, I'd recommend at least adding a note to your answers disclosing that the link is to your personal github/wesbite/blog etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks for the note. I think it is clear that is is my website since it contains my username `cirosantilli` on the URL? I could inline more things, but it would mean a lot of copy pasting, and if one day I notice something was wrong, several answers will be wrong. Also, those links will be forever valid, as I always use SHA URLs and will never delte the repo. I really only link so that people will have a full minimal working example, which is what I myself searched before creating the repo ;-)

Comment: I didn't notice for a lot of your original answers that that the github was yours.When looking at a big long URL I don't generally pay attention to the contents inside the URL itself.I think the SO FAQ is pretty clear about it. We don't know if you'll ever delete the repo or that github won't go under. I did note that at least you posted the relevant snippets IN your answers so that if github ceases to be available or you did delete the repo - your answers are still relevant. For the most part your answers actually don't need the link to github because you've provided the useful bits inline.

Comment: You could always ask on Meta SO whether others feel that the GITHUB URL is enough indicator to identify it as yours.

Comment: @MichaelPetch No worries, if you think it's not clear it will not be clear for some other people, so I'll just try to write "my GitHub" from now on ;-)